# d3.js range of values for lab colour

Tags: colors, d3.js

I am working on an X-colours palette (kinda like [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/sxv/4616231)) but based on d3's lab colour space implementation. I have read the documentation [here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3014589), [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Colors#lab) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space), even had a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/color/lab.js) and I figured that l-value must be within [0,100] but I couldn't find a range for a and b. Does any value work with them or are they bound to a specific range (like [0, 255] for rgb for example)?

Comment: I would expect them to be in the range [0,100].

Comment: After [playing around](http://jsfiddle.net/RFontana/s3Sy3/) with the LAB scale it seems to me that a and b are unbounded, or rather that meaningful values for them depend on L... I am thinking of reducing the Lab space to a 2D space by picking a fixed L but I feel like this isn't the right solution either

Comment: Check out [HUSL](http://boronine.com/husl/), which uses the CIE LChuv colorspace, but converts it to an HSL-like space which is easier to use programatically (i.e. well defined ranges). I'm not sure if you could use it directly, but you could at least look at the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The *a* parameter is a point in the range yellow-blue component and the *b* parameter is a value in the green-magenta component. It's hard to determine valid range values for *a* and *b*, as the valid range depends on the value of the parameter *L* (which is expected to be in the range [0, 100]). [This article](http://vis4.net/blog/posts/avoid-equidistant-hsv-colors/) contains more details. You could use [`d3.interpolateLab(l, a, b)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-d3_interpolateLab). In this context, a and b are object that can be interpreted as colors (string, `d3.rgb, d3.hsv`).