# d3.js interpolate between two hex colors

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors

I need to use d3.js to interpolate between two hex colors.  I need to interpolate between #01579b and #f34e54. The scale ranges from 0 - 97.  So if a user inputs 0, the color output will be #01579b.  If the user inputs 97, the color output will be #f34e54.  All  inputs (0,1,2,3,4...97) will need to transition smoothly between the two hex colors.  I need to clamp the output.  How can I accomplish this with d3.js?  If this question is unclear, please let me know how I can clarify.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why don't you use a basic linear scale? Did you try it?

Comment: You need to convert the hex formatted rgb color to a LAB colorant and use that. How to do that could be answered elsewhere https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590284/d3-js-range-of-values-for-lab-colour

Comment: There's probably a better duplicate candidate, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27574081/7106086) might help. It's d3v3, but the only difference is `d3.scale.linear` is now `d3.scaleLinear`

Comment: @RikkuBölske That's not necessary, OP can use hex as it is: https://jsfiddle.net/1gzh7gf5/

Comment: var scale = d3.scaleLinear().clamp(true).domain([0,97])
.range(['#01579b', '#f34e54']);

This works just fine.  Thanks people.